# skype: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: software-installation, skype

I have a problem with Skype on Kubuntu 14.04 x64. Skype does not start and throws

```
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I have a backup of my system. When I do rollback then all works fine, but after some time past (1-2 weeks) Skype will not run with the message above.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem running binaries compiled with g++ under a 64bit ubuntu 14.04 installation.

I installed g++-multilib and everything runs fine now

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this solution been mentioned:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

Not sure if it applies to your situation, though.

Answer (score -1):

This means that the library is 64 bit, which skype is not expecting. Possibly because you've installed 32-bit skype.
You can either try and get 64-bit skype, or install the 32 bit libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: There is no 64-bit Skype, and ia32-libs is not available in trusty.

Comment: hummm, try maybe libc6-i386?